# Sending JSON data to client triggered on reading from a file

Tags: node.js

I have log files (1-2 MB in size) that I want to read using node.js. Thanks to help on this forum I am using something like:

```
new lazy(fs.createReadStream(clientMessage.selectedFile))
.lines
.forEach(function(line){
sendData(line,client,playBackSpeed);});
```

The sendData function is essentially a parser, using a switch, that collects data from the log file, line by line. Here is a snippet of that parser in the sendData function:

```
    switch (lineTokens[0]) //first token is the command idenitifier
    {
        case "$F":{ // heartbeat signal
                var elapspedTimeIndex = 4, flagIndex = 5;
                var heartBeat = "{\"heartBeat\": {\"elapsedTime\":"+ lineTokens[elapspedTimeIndex].trim() +", \"flag\":"+ lineTokens[flagIndex].trim() + "}}";
                var now = new Date().getTime();
                while(new Date().getTime() <= now + playBackSpeed) {} //sleep before we move on
                client.send(heartBeat);
            }
            return;
        }
}
```

I what to send the data out at regular intervals, say between 1 - 5 seconds. In the client UI there is a way change the desired playback speed. The code above works fine but I am not able to change the value of playBackSpeed after this file stream has started. I am using socket.io to do message exchange and that is working fine. It seems that the while loop that creates the delay is blocking the client/server exchange. I tried putting in a setTimeout but all that did was delay for the playbackSpeed interval and send all the data to client all at once. I am sure this is an I/O blocking issue but, I just can seem to dig out of this.

Answer (score 0):

push data to a FIFO buffer and send it using timer events

```
switch (lineTokens[0]) //first token is the command idenitifier
    {
        case "$F":{ // heartbeat signal
                var elapspedTimeIndex = 4, flagIndex = 5;
                var heartBeat = "{\"heartBeat\": {\"elapsedTime\":"+ lineTokens[elapspedTimeIndex].trim() +", \"flag\":"+ lineTokens[flagIndex].trim() + "}}";
                client.queue.add(heartBeat);
            }
            return;
        }
}

function checkQueue()
{
    var msg = client.queue.pop();
    if (!msg) return;
    client.send(msg);
}

function setSpeed(newSpeed)
{
    if (timerID)
        clearInterval(timerID);
    timerID = setInterval(checkQueue, playBackSpeed);
}

setSpeed(playBackSpeed);
```